# Jquery function on Dynamically created List not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Please Help me out, I can get the dynamic list on the second Page and all is Ok. But when i click any "li" to get alert of the "id" (which works fine for hard coded list) i dont get any thing. I have tried listview('refresh') and (trigger) too but no effect. Most of the other questions were solved with the help of listview("refresh") but not in my case. Please see if you can point me in the right direction.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#page1',function(){
        $("#bar .type").click(function(){
            localStorage['ppl']=$(this).attr('id');
            $.mobile.changePage("#second",{
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: true
            });
        });
    });
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#second',function(){
        var ty =  localStorage['ppl'];
        getOther(ty);// THIS POPULATE THE LIST
        /*THESE ONES DONT WORK FOR ME */
        //$(document).trigger('create');
        //$('[data-role="listview"]').listview("refresh");
        //$('#foo).listview('refresh');
        $("#foo li").click(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));// NO ALERT FROM THIS NEW LIST
            $.mobile.changePage('#third',{
                transition: "slide",
                reverse:true
            });
        });
    });
```

this the HTML Code.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div  data-role="header"><h3>First Page</h3></div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <ul id="bar">
        <li class="type" id="A" value="A">A</li>
        <li class="type" id="B" value="B">B</li>
    </ul>
</div><div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="second">
<div data-role="header">    <h3>Second Page</h3>
    <a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a></div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="status">
<!--THIS LIST IS CREATED AFTER CLICKING EITHER "A" OR "B"--->
     <ul id="foo" data-role="listview">
       <li id="AB">AB</li>
       <li id="AC">AC</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="third"><div data-role="header"><h3>Third Page</h3><a href="#second" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a></div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="status2">

    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"></div></div>
```

Comment: Use event delegation: $("#foo").on("click", "li", function(){...  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @ezanker thanks for reply but still unsuccessful

Comment: post jsfiddle if possible

Comment: Don't use `pagebeforeshow` to bind events, you'll end up multiplying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing lots of research, and scratchings of head i did some changes to code and got the result. Thanks for you help.
Firstly for my function"getOther(ty);" i added it into the body,

```
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#page1',function(){
 AND IN IT I PUT THIS LINE
$("#foo").append($("<li></li>")).listview("refresh");
```

and it did the trick for adding the dynamic list into the DOM.
And the for attaching click function to "li" I was using

```
$("#foo li").click(function(){

alert($(this).attr('id'));// NO ALERT FROM THIS NEW LIST
```

I changed it to

```
$("#foo").on('click','li',function(){
```

and It worked. Thank you for your help. Much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery "on" method instead of 'click'.

```
$("#foo").find('li').on(function(){
     localStorage['ppl']=$(this).attr('id');
     $.mobile.changePage("#second",{
        transition: "slide",
        reverse: true
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your code so that the click handlers are created on pagecreate. So when page1 is created, add the event handler for clicking the #bar.type items. Then when second page is created use event delegation to add a handler to the LI's within foo. Because these LI's are dynamic and not available when the handler is added, you actually need to add the handler to the UL and delegate it to its LI's.

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','#page1',function(){
    $("#bar .type").click(function(){
        localStorage['ppl']=$(this).attr('id');
        $.mobile.changePage("#second",{
            transition: "slide",
            reverse: true
        });
    });
});
$(document).on('pagecreate','#second',function(){
    $("#foo").on("click", "li", function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));// NO ALERT FROM THIS NEW LIST
        $.mobile.changePage('#third',{
            transition: "slide",
            reverse:true
        });
    });    
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#second',function(){
    var ty =  localStorage['ppl'];
    getOther(ty);// THIS POPULATE THE LIST
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/qmwjeyk0/)**